# How to start a HTML 5 video from a particular position?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="Video.mp4#t=03,20" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

The videos starts from 3 minutes 20 seconds in my code. I want to play video from beginning after setting #t=03,20 in html5. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<video id="vid1" width="320" height="240" controls loop>
  <source src="Video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

You have to wait until the browser knows the duration of the video before you can seek to a particular time.

```
     <script>
      window.onload=function(){
                  document.getElementById('vid1').addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
                  this.currentTime = 200;
            }, false  );

       };             
     </script>
```

**OR**

```
function restart1() 
{ var video1 = document.getElementById("vid1");
 video1.currentTime = 0; 
} 

<video id="vid1" width="320" height="240" onclick="restart1();" controls> 
       <source src="Videos.mp4#t=03,61" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag. 
</video>
```

Comment: put it in the `<head>` portion of your webpage

Comment: Have a look at this page (http://gingertech.net/2009/08/19/jumping-to-time-offsets-in-videos/) for details.

Comment: function restart1() {
     var video1 = document.getElementById("vid1");
     video1.currentTime = 0;
                    }                                           <video id="vid1" width="320" height="240" onclick="restart1();" controls>
  <source src="Videos.mp4#t=03,61" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>